# How to generate key from Provider in Consumer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to "read a provider immediately when creating it" in `context.watch<FooModel>().foo`, which would trigger an error.

How to obtain a new `BuildContext` and generate a value from it?

```
Consumer<FooModel>(
  key: ValueKey( context.watch<FooModel>().foo ),
  builder: (context, value, child) {
    return fooWidget;
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply wrap the child part of the provider into another class, to prevent reading a provider immediately. It worked.